# SQL Fewer Columns Than Were Specified

Tags: sql, join

I'm running the following query in SQL server and it's giving me the error:

'Results' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list.

I'm clearly listing several columns so I'm not sure what the problem is.  I tried putting only Results( ContractDesc ) and it resolved the error, so I guess it thinks I'm only selecting one column inside that query.  How do I solve this?

```
SELECT
Cl.LegalName AS ClientNames,
Results.ContractDesc AS ContractNames,
Results.ProjectNames AS ProjectNames,
Results.EmployeeNames AS EmployeeNames,
Results.TotalHours AS TotalHours, 
Results.TotalCharges AS TotalCharges, 
Results.BillingContacts AS BillingContacts

FROM Clients Cl

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
    ( Cr.ContractDesc + ', ' ) AS ContractDesc, 
    ( P.ProjectName + ', ' ) AS ProjectNames, 
    ( E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName + ', ' ) AS EmployeeNames,
    ( WH.HoursWorked + ', ' ) AS TotalHours,
    ( WH.HoursWorked * BR.Rate ) + ', ' AS TotalCharges,
    ( Ca.FirstName + Ca.LastName + ', ' + Ca.AddrLine1 + ', ' ) AS BillingContacts

    FROM Contracts Cr

    JOIN Projects P ON( Cr.ContractID = P.ContractID )
    JOIN EmployeesProjects EP ON( P.ProjectID = EP.ProjectID )
    JOIN Employees E ON( EP.EmpID = E.EmpID )
    JOIN WorkHours WH ON( E.EmpID = WH.EmpID )
    JOIN BillingRates BR ON( E.TitleID = BR.TitleID ) AND ( E.Level = BR.Level )
    JOIN ContractsContacts CC ON( Cr.ContractID = CC.ContractID )
    JOIN Contacts Ca ON( CC.ContactID = Ca.ContactID )

    WHERE( Cl.ClientID = Cr.ClientID )
    AND ( WH.WH_Month = 4 )
    AND ( WH.WH_Year = 2013 )

    GROUP BY Cr.ContractID,
    Cr.ContractDesc,
    P.ProjectName,
    E.FirstName,
    E.LastName,
    WH.HoursWorked,
    BR.Rate,
    Ca.FirstName,
    Ca.LastName,
    Ca.AddrLine1

    FOR XML PATH( '' )
) Results ( ContractDesc, ProjectNames, EmployeeNames, TotalHours, TotalCharges, BillingContacts )
```

Comment: `FOR XML PATH()` is going to create a single XML document. It's not going to have 6 columns with the names you're giving on that final line.

Comment: Oh I see now, is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?  I want to return several rows of concatenated results

Answer (score 2):

**ClientNames** appears to be missing from Results().

Comment: I'm getting that from the Clients table, not Results()